# Azure Role Assignment for Get-AzureVM?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-virtual-machine

I would like to use [Role-based access control](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/role-based-access-control-configure/) to give an account the ability to administer certain VMs. The VMs are in a resource group.

```
New-AzureRoleAssignment -Mail user@mycompany.onmicrosoft.com -RoleDefinitionName Reader -ResourceGroupName somevms

New-AzureRoleAssignment -Mail user@mycompany.onmicrosoft.com -RoleDefinitionName 'Virtual Machine Contributor' -ResourceGroupName somevms
```

It doesn't seem to work for me. In order for the user to successfully run commands like Get-AzureVM, I have to add them as a subscription `Co-administrator` which is not what I want to do.

Is it possible to allow a user to do a `Get-AzureVM` using Role-based access control?